# PocketBeagle Debian internet over USB

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am trying to follow directions from the book [Exploring Beaglebone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118935128). I have also viewed [this video](https://youtu.be/Cf9hnscbSK8) which is wrong OSes. I have also read some posts ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434281/beaglebone-black-persistent-internet-over-usb-debian-image-2016-05-13-am335x-e), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782634/steps-to-share-internet-with-beaglebone-black-using-usb-from-os-x/30581692#30581692)).

Observed anomalies:

Network Preferences shows a warning of a self-assigned IP address and inability to support internet sharing:
[macOS Network Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcvKN.png)

Debian does not have a 'udhcpc' command but the following was executed:
[Screen output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTeBT.png)

Has anyone been able to do internet over USB on macOS 10.13.2 and Debian 9 IoT?

tnx,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

So a quick intro to what options you have:

- Manually enable routing + NAT (No idea how to do that on OSX)
- Configure the board system to use DHCP client functionality instead to talk to a shared connection from e.g. OSX.

  - Permanently disable the script (should be in `/opt` somewhere) that assigns the current network settings and enables DHCP serving. Might also just be a part of a larger script.
  - Enable DHCP client (e.g. in `/etc/network/interfaces` or by using Connman or Network-manager)

The default Debian image should also expose a serial console over USB. You can use this to gain access to and configure the system even when your network connection doesn't work. Of course, the debug-UART should work as well, by using a USB-serial converter.

Another note: the DHCP client on Debian for manual execution is usually `dhclient`. The interface on the Beaglebone side will be named `usb0` or `usb1` (as newer images use two types for increased compatibility e.g. with OSX).

A good place to ask questions is usually the [Beagleboard Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/beagleboard)

Comment: I have posted this same thing there (BBB Google group) also.

Typically, I one 'shares' the 'internet' connection with the beaglebone (i.e., via bridge). This, I have done on previous releases with a BBB running Ångstrom. Either something has changed in macOS 10.13 or PB/Debian. As this used to work on my BBB.